# React map textinput manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm struggling arround with manipulation of a . I want to archive that onFocus the current value is selected so that the user can easy override it instead of delete the current value and input the new value.

And i also want to always add a suffix to the input value (${Strings.ST262} / ${Strings.ST261} = Reps / kg) but if i add this to "value" of the TextInput i can't change it anymore (is autoupdated to the initial value)

Hopefully anyone can help

```
const [textArray, setTextArray] = useState(Array.from({ length: exercises.length }, () => Array.from({ length: maxSets }, () => '')));
const [focusedIndex, setFocusedIndex] = useState(null);

const handleTextChange = (text, index1, index2) => {
  const newTextArray = [...textArray];
  newTextArray[index1][index2] = parseFloat(text) || ''; // convert text to a number or empty string if NaN
  setTextArray(newTextArray);
};

const handleFocus = (index1, index2) => {
  setFocusedIndex([index1, index2]);
};


return (
    <ScrollView>
   
        {/*console.log(allWorkoutData)*/}
        {map(allWorkoutData, (item, i) => (
          <View style={innerStyles.item_container} key={i}>
 
                  <View style={{...innerStyles.item_container}}>
                    {item.setsData.map((set, setIndex) => (
                      <View style={{width:screenWidth, marginTop:0, alignContent:'center', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}} key={`SetView-${item.exercise_id}-${setIndex}`}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} key={setIndex}>
                          <View style={{...innerStyles.item_container_child}}>
                            <TextInput
                              key={`RepsInput-${i}-${item.exercise_id}-${setIndex}`}
                              placeholder={`${set.reps} ${Strings.ST262}`}
                              mode="flat"
                              onChangeText={(text) => handleTextChange(text, i, setIndex * 2)}
                              onFocus={() => handleFocus(i, setIndex * 2)}
                              onBlur={handleBlur}
                              defaultValue={`${set.reps}`}
                              keyboardType="numeric"
                              autoCapitalize="none"
                              style={innerStyles.item_input_text}
                           />
          
                          </View>
                          <View style={{...innerStyles.item_container_child}}>
                            <TextInput
                              key={`WeightInput-${i}-${item.exercise_id}-${setIndex}`}
                              placeholder={`${set.weight} ${Strings.ST261}`}
                              onChangeText={(text) => handleTextChange(text, i, setIndex * 2 + 1)}
                              onFocus={() => handleFocus(i, setIndex * 2 + 1)}
                              onBlur={handleBlur}
                              defaultValue={`${set.weight}`}
                              keyboardType="numeric"
                              autoCapitalize="none"
                              style={innerStyles.item_input_text}
                            />
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      </View> 
                    ))}
                  </View>
          </View>
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].